# Is there a way I can calculate the mean of certain parts of a table in a list of files of the similar problems in r?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a list of files with similar tables but different dimensions. I want to do a for loop in r to calculate the mean and SD for the cost values inside rows/columns, last rows(Demand) and last column(supply) separately and save a in a file to use.

I am still new to r. Thanks in advance.

This is what it looks like
[image]

Comment: Can you show the expected output for the input

Comment: The expected output should have a list of tables for each files showing mean of cost/SD of cost, mean of last row /SD of last row(Demand) and mean of last column/SD of last column(Supply). Thanks Mean Cost SD Cost Mean Dem SD Dem Mean Su SD Sup
Table1      
Table2      
Table3

Comment: Which is the cost column?

Comment: some first steps are obvious.  it would be good to show your attempt.

Comment: The mean cost are all values in column 1, 2 and 3, except the last rows and last column.

Comment: @akrun. expected output  will be: Supply_mean = (20+ 18+18+38)/4, Cost_mean=(11+6+6+10+11+8+5+6+8+7+11+10)/12, Demand_mean = (42 +42 +10)/3.                          Supply_mean= 23.5, Cost_mean = 8.25, Demand_mean = 31.33.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

mean(mydata[-nrow(mydata), -ncol(mydata)])

This worked for finding the mean of the Cost except the last row and last column.

Thanks